# HTML img srcset/size not working on iPhone 4S

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I've created a webpage based on Eric Portis's excellent article "[Srcset and sizes](http://ericportis.com/posts/2014/srcset-sizes/)" but it's not working properly on my iPhone 4s.  As I understand it, the 4s is 320 virtual (or CSS) pixels wide but since the 4S has a Retina display, this actually translates to 640 (= 2 x 320) virtual pixels.  When I view the code shown below on my iPhone (in portrait mode), I see two rows of the "large" image with each image in each of the two rows taking up one-third of the viewport's width.  I don't think this is right.

If I understand my img size attibute correctly, it's saying that if the browser sees that the viewport has a minimum width of 768 pixels, each image should take up 1/3 of the viewport's width.  Otherwise, take up 100%:

```
sizes='(min-width: 768px) 33.3vw, 100vw'
```

But since the width of my iPhone viewport is 640 pixels, shouldn't I be seeing one image per row with each image taking up the entire width of the viewport?

As you can see, I'm using Scott Jehl's picturefill polyfill so that the browser won't default to the image URL in the src attribute.  My small, medium, and large images have widths of 100, 200, and 300 pixels respectively.  Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test Srcset/Sizes</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        * { box-sizing: border-box; }
        body, figure { margin: 0; }
        img { display: block; width: 100%; }
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            text-align: center;
        }
        h1 {
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 2em;
            margin: 0.5em;
            text-align: center;

        }
        figure {
            padding: 1px;
        }
        @media (min-width: 768px) {
            figure {
                display: block;
                float: left;
                width: 33.3333333333333%;
            }
        }
    </style>
    <script>
    document.createElement("picture");
    </script>
    <script src="../js/picturefill.min.js" async></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Srcset and Sizes</h1>
    <main>
    <figure>
        <img src='img/mine/small-1.jpg' 
             srcset='img/mine/large-1.jpg 300w,
                     img/mine/medium-1.jpg 200w,
                     img/mine/small-1.jpg 100w'
             sizes='(min-width: 768px) 33.3vw,
                    100vw'
             alt="Image 1" />
    </figure><!--

    --><figure>
        <img src='img/mine/small-2.jpg' 
             srcset='img/mine/large-2.jpg 300w,
                     img/mine/medium-2.jpg 200w,
                     img/mine/small-2.jpg 100w'
             sizes='(min-width: 768px) 33.3vw,
                    100vw'
             alt="Image 2" />
    </figure><!--

    --><figure>
        <img src='img/mine/small-3.jpg' 
             srcset='img/mine/large-3.jpg 300w,
                     img/mine/medium-3.jpg 200w,
                     img/mine/small-3.jpg 100w'
             sizes='(min-width: 768px) 33.3vw,
                    100vw'
             alt="Image 3" />
    </figure><!--

    --><figure>
        <img src='img/mine/small-4.jpg' 
             srcset='img/mine/large-4.jpg 300w,
                     img/mine/medium-4.jpg 200w,
                     img/mine/small-4.jpg 100w'
             sizes='(min-width: 768px) 33.3vw,
                    100vw'
             alt="Image 4" />
    </figure><!--

    --><figure>
        <img src='img/mine/small-5.jpg' 
             srcset='img/mine/large-5.jpg 300w,
                     img/mine/medium-5.jpg 200w,
                     img/mine/small-5.jpg 100w'
             sizes='(min-width: 768px) 33.3vw,
                    100vw'
             alt="Image 5" />
    </figure><!--

    --><figure>
        <img src='img/mine/small-6.jpg' 
             srcset='img/mine/large-6.jpg 300w,
                     img/mine/medium-6.jpg 200w,
                     img/mine/small-6.jpg 100w'
             sizes='(min-width: 768px) 33.3vw,
                    100vw'
             alt="Image 6" />
    </figure>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Safari doesn't have support for `sizes`, nor for `srcset`'s `w` descriptor.
WebKit nightlies support it, but it wasn't turned on in the Safari branch as far as testing shows.

Your example works fine in Chrome 38 AFAICT.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem may be that you're using min-width. When using min-width in your media query you're telling the browser to apply the following styling when the browser window is larger than the following value. I believe if you use max-width in this case that you will get the desired results.

Here's [an article](http://unmatchedstyle.com/news/working-with-media-queries-and-min-width.php) for a little more info on this topic.

Comment: I don't think using min-width is the problem.  The sizes attribute is saying if the width is >= 768, show three images, each 33.3% the width of the screen.  But it's doing that even if the width is less than 768.

Comment: Ah, I think I misinterpreted before. I was also being a little lazy and didn't take the time to read the article that you linked to the first time.

With that being said, I'm not sure why this isn't working in the browser in your phone. It works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/ctgunn/hzfLhuL1/. Also according to this I think it should be supported unless your browser on your phone is not up to date. http://caniuse.com/#search=srcset.

Hope this helps.